# "can agree" versus "agree"?

Tags: usage

I want to know which one of the following sentences is better (maybe both sentences have flaws) :

> They can agree that we start the meeting first.

or

> They agree that we start the meeting first.

Comment: They are both grammatical. They have possibly different meanings (the first implying that 'they' have considered constraints they face).

Answer (score 1):

> They can agree that we start the meeting first.

means that they have the possibility to agree while

> They agree that we start the meeting first.

means they agree to first start with the meeting.

Comment: And the first sentence suggests that usually they don't agree!

Comment: @user21820 Yup, if we mention the possibility, there is strong chances that they don't agree. But they can also agree while they were not supposed to ! Mentionning the possibility often underline the fact people didn't act as we would guess, **not only negatively**.

Comment: Yup my thoughts exactly.

Comment: I read "they can agree" as being an unconfirmed expectation, or maybe a hesitant agreement, whereas "they agree" indicates they have already made their agreement known. It seems awkward to say "they can agree" because if their agreement is fully known, "they agree" is the least ambiguous way to write that. On the other hand, If their agreement is not confirmed, some other word(s) would better portray the situation. "They might agree," or "they will probably agree," or "they hesitantly agree" each paint more descriptive scenarios than "can" is able to.